Convert unique_ptr of derived class to unique_tr of base class with custom deleter class
I am facing problems trying to convert the unique pointer unique_ptr<Derived,Deleter<Derived>> to the unique pointer unique_ptr<Base,Deleter<Base>>. The class Derived is, of course, derived from the class Base, and the template class Deleter overloads the () operator to create a custom deletion routine to the unique pointer. Using std::move returns an error and all my other attemps have failed. Is this conversion really possible?.
class Base
{

};

class Derived : public Base
{

};

template <typename T> class Deleter
{
public:
 void operator()(T* pointer)
 {
   //custom deletion
 }
};

int main()
{
 std::unique_ptr<Derived,Deleter<Derived>> derived_pointer(new Derived(), Deleter<Derived>());
 std::unique_ptr<Base,Deleter<Base>> base_pointer=std::move(derived_pointer);//error, conversion not possible
 return 0;
}


What is "an error"? Show it!

You need a conversion between the two deleters to be defined. See constructor #6 here.
